# Prevent executing mathematical expression in input field when adding value to MySQL (PHP)

Tags: php, date, expression, textinput

I have set up the following form:

```
<form name="pric" method="post" action="up.php">
    <div id="prices_col">Season A<br>
        <input type='text' name="date0" maxlength="13" size="15" style="font-size: 9px;" value="<?php echo $_date[0]?>" />
    </div>
    <div align="middle"><input type="submit" value="EDIT"></div>
</form>
```

Information in database right now was like this ($_date[0] contains):

> 04/06 - 25/06

After posting the information, it decided to run the expression and I got something like:

> -1.333333333

I use the following code:

```
$_date[0] = trim($_POST["date0"]);
mysql_query("UPDATE price SET _date=".$_date[0]." WHERE id='0'") or die(mysql_error());
```

How can I stop it from executing? I need to store the value as a plain text to the database.

Comment: What does `$_date[0]` contain? What's in up.php?

Comment: can we see the PHP form up.php?

Comment: how are you getting the -1.3333? SELECT COUNT(date_field)??

Comment: Try `<?php echo htmlentities( $_date[0] ); ?>`

Comment: I edited description :) $_date[0] contains 04/06 - 25/06

Comment: What type of field is the "date" field in the database?

Comment: date='"$_date[0]."'   with single quotes for TEXT

Comment: date is the type of text

Comment: Waygood if I write as you said, I get error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `price` SET `_date`='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["date0"]))."' WHERE `id`=0") or die(mysql_error());
```

as _date is a text field and mysql_real_escape_string for security

Comment: are your quoting the date? i've added mysql_real_escape_string too. echo the sql first to see what your doing. $sql="....."; echo $sql; mysql_query($sql);